# 404 not found for plp , pdp, homepage, customer pages, contact us etc... : M2

Tags: 404-page, magento2-enterprise

only cms pages are working good,  all other pages like homepage, product listing page, product detail page, customer login & register, contact us etc... all pages are showing as 404 not found.

i have try to clear & disable cache, re-indexing and also try to run commands but still other pages are not working.

i have also try to disable "Use Web Server Rewrites" and also with my custom theme.

404 not found error is showing in browser's console and network tab.

Comment: Any indication in error logs?

Comment: no, not getting any help from log file

Comment: Try and check :
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*

Comment: check server/Magento logs

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on the server?

Comment: have you checked is there .htacces file in root ?

Comment: can you provide site url ?

Comment: there is some issue from database side.

Comment: @mukesh , It's at my localhost server.